# null / DBNull conversion

Tags: c#, null, dbnull

i have a method

```
void addParam(string name, object value);
```

and an object

```
public class Foo 
{
   public string Whatever;
}
```

what is the best way to perform a (working) call that would match this logic?

```
addParam("foo", Foo.Whatever == null ? DBNull.Value : Foo.Whatever);
```

I was thinking about such a thing like this:

```
object getParamValue(object value)
{
  if (value == null) return DBNull.Value;
  return value;
}

addParam("foo", getParamValue(ValueFoo.Whatever));
```

How can i achieve this behavior?

Comment: What is wrong with the code your posting -- I don't see a question here.

Comment: Your solution looks fine!

Comment: You can save some space using null coalescing operator: addParam("foo", Foo.Whatever ?? DBNull.Value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use null coalesce operation:

```
addParam("foo", Foo.Whatever ?? DBNull.Value);
```